# How to Form a Polars DataFrame from SQL Alchemy Asynchronous Query Result?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, python-polars

The title says it all. Here is the code snippet.

```py
async with EngineContext(uri=URI) as engine:
    session = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True)()
    async with session.begin():
        stmt: Select = select(User).order_by(_GenerativeSelect__first=User.login_date.desc()).limit(limit=10)
        result = await session.execute(statement=stmt)
```

Equivalent to the very simple query,

```sql
SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY login_date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The query is working fine and I am getting the results as expected. But I want to form a polars dataframe from the result, and without having to hardcode (or externally supply) the column names. I cannot seem to get the correct public APIs of the result object to manage it. When I try `result.keys()`, I get `RMKeyView(['User'])`, not the column names.

I tried iterating over the results, where each object has the column names as attributes, but there are many other attributes. So the code cannot be dynamic enough to pick up the column names.

So any help on the cleanest way to form a polars Dataframe (preferably lazy) from this result?

Related, when I begin the session, is there a way to explicitly mark the session as read-only in SQL alchemy, to preclude any possibility of data corruption when no write is intended in that session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# 1. the select query
sele = select(User).order_by(User.login_date.desc()).limit(10)
print(sele)

# 2. create a STRING statement from it
stmt = str(sele.compile(
    dialect=session.bind.dialect,
    compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True},
))
print(stmt)

# 3. this is the ACTUAL ANSWER part
import polars as pl
res = pl.read_database(stmt, session)
print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting ```NotImplementedError: Currently no support for 'sqlalchemy' connection <sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.session.AsyncSession object at 0x7f1a7b7350d0>```, but I believe it's a driver issue. Nevertheless, your answer showed me it is possible to get the raw SQL statement out of the alchemy ORM query, which I hope will serve me well under the right circumstances. I solved this problem by going around the issue, as I wrote in my own answer.

Comment: It is strange that this solution does not work for you. It works for me with the following versions of `sqlalchemy` and `polars`: `sa.__version__='2.0.21', pl.__version__='0.19.5'` for both `sqlite` and `postgresql`. But I was not testing `async` workflow, which might be the actual reason why this does not work.

Comment: I am using MySQL and ```aiomysql==0.2.0``` driver, I suspect the asynchronous request is the culprit, but given the nature of my application architecture, it is hard to get rid of async for just that one method now. So I am resorting to my alternative solution, you can take a look and suggest if there is a way to make it cleaner. In particular, it would be great if I could get the column names from ```data```, the query result, instead of the original ORM object.

Comment: I have tested async version at my end and get the same error as you do.

Answer (score 2):

Support for user-supplied connection objects was only added to polars very recently (by me ;). If you can make this into a [feature request](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/new?labels=enhancement&projects=&template=feature_request.yml) on our GitHub repo I'd be happy to take a look and see if there's something we can do to add support for this.

Note that in the most recent Polars releases we now support the use of SQLAlchemy "Selectable" query objects (in conjunction with SQLAclehmy connections), so you wouldn't need to translate to string in advance, you can pass the "select" object straight in).

The upcoming `0.19.9` release (coming soon) will also support [batched](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11664) DataFrame iteration over database queries.

Comment: I tried searching for "sqlalchemy async" on the issues tracker but not seeing anything related to sqlalchemy + async. would the feature request be "read_database to support sqlachemy2 asynchronous connections"? i feel like im missing something thats already implemented somehow

Answer (score 2):

FYI: once this PR merges Polars will support seamless DataFrame init from `async` SQLAlchemy connections, engines, and sessions: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/15162.

Answer (score 0):

After some pain, I got this piece of rather convoluted mess working, but I believe there should be a cleaner way to do it.

```py
def column_to_series(column: str) -> pl.Series:
    """Convert a column to a series based on DB query results """
    return pl.Series(name=column,
                     values=map(lambda item: getattr(
                         item[0], column), data))

async with EngineContext(uri=URI) as engine:
    session: Any = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True)()
    async with session.begin():
        stmt: Select = select(User).order_by(
            _GenerativeSelect__first=User.login_date.desc()).limit(limit=n)
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        data: List[Tuple[User]] = (await session.execute(
            statement=stmt)).fetchall()
        columns: Iterator[str] = map(lambda item: getattr(item, 'key'),
                                     inspect(subject=User).c)
        res:pl.DataFrame=await pl.LazyFrame(data=map(column_to_series,
                                            columns)).collect_async()
```

Van's solution fails because apparently, polars and aiomysql driver do not play well with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue, read_database() doesn't play nice with sqlalchemy async stuff (as of jan2024) AFAIK.

Add another way to do it similar to Della's answer

```
class SourceInstancesTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "instances"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=True)
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True)

df = polars.DataFrame()
async with source as session: # (ive wrapped the session create and engine in an async context manager but this wont change the "answer")
    sql = select(SourceInstancesTable)
    records = await session.stream(sql)
    async for row in records:
        row = polars.DataFrame({k: [v] for (k, v) in row._mapping.items()})
        df = df.vstack(row)
df = df.rechunk()
print(df)
```

Can pretty much use any normal sqlalchemy stmt with this at least and it streams the results in. Added benefit of if you do joins and stuff it should still work fine without having to re-declare schemas.

Turns the record result to a dict then creates the polars dataframe from that dict. I hate using the private API tho but it works at least.